# Editing .XML File Using a PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file which I would like to create a form/table around to add, edit and delete records using PHP.

Is there any way I can create a table that shows all results, and allows me to either edit or delete that particular row of the table which represents a full record within the XML file ?

i want to be able to add/edit/delete tags using my web browser only without editing the xml file on pc and uploading to FTP..

I need this done in PHP, javascript or any other way to do so.

> Please dont give me links for simpleXML coz i tried this and i didn't mange to make it work coz i dont know anything about PHP :(

it would be much appreciated if someone can do it for me!
Thanks!

my xml file (scores.xml) looks like that :

```
<SCORES>
<GAME>
<DATE>14.5.2012 12:05</DATE>
<TIME>FT</TIME>
<HOMETEAM>Team1</HOMETEAM>
<SCORE>4 - 0</SCORE>
<AWAYTEAM>Team2</AWAYTEAM>
<OTHER> </OTHER>
<INFO><![CDATA[<img class='info1' src='images/info.png' width='14px' height='14px' border='0' />]]></INFO>
<INFOID>info1</INFOID>
<INFODATA>FIRST BUBBLE</INFODATA>
</GAME>
</SCORES>
```

Answer (score 1):

Load and manipulate it with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), then upload it with the PHP [FTP library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php).

Comment: lots of people telling me about SimpleXML but i read on this website and i didnt manage to know how to install it and use it ... :S

Comment: You shouldn't need to install it - it's a default library in PHP. For help with using it, this answer is a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092172/edit-xml-with-simplexml.

Comment: i can't get this done i don't know anything about PHP im so lost....
i wrote here hoping someone could help me by giving me the code... :/

Comment: "hoping someone could help me by giving me the code: - Yeah I don't think that's going to happen buddy. Learn the PHP you need.

Comment: If you can't use PHP, then your problems are only just beginning - I'd suggest hiring a freelancer if you need it urgently.